# PDF Thumbnails on windows server 2008 R2 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, thumbnails, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to display PDF thumbnails on asp.net website.

When I am running the website on my local mechine from visual studio debug- the thumbnail images are displayed (tiff or pdf).

When I run the site on the server after publishing it (Windows Server 2008 R2, ServicePack1, 64bit) - the tiff thumbnails are displayed as expected, but PDF thumbnails displayed as AdobeReader icons (not the first page of the PDF file).

Windows Explorer on the server displayes the PDF thumbnails correctly.

The code I write for displaying thumbnails(using WindowsAPICodePack):

```
 using (ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(curPath))
 {
     using (Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.MediumBitmap)
     {
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
              shellThumb.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
              var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
              imgFile.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Data);
              imgFile.Visible = true;
          }
     }
 }
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution , didn't find one yet.
 
Maybe someone knows , instead of the code above-
 
How can I save the first page of pdf file as small image?
 
I found some solutions but none of them worked for me because I need c# code that works on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I used WindowsAPICodePack with asp.net too, but in the server you will need to install a pdf viewer that generates the thumbnail. If you don't have access to the server admin account forget it.

I tried first Adobe Reader XI, but it have a bug with the thumbnail preview on 64 bits https://forums.adobe.com/message/3905029. They suggest to apply this fix http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/index.html#downl but I want to evict some hidden hack that takes the control of my server! So I don't install it.

Then I installed http://www.win7pdf.com/pdf-preview.html and it worked fine. The thumb image quality is less than the adobe pdf one, but it's just a thumb.